# how to set up the scale of yAxis in D3.js with a csv file with multiple columns

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been playing with D3.js recently and trying to make a small map application with it. Basicly ,the app will show a world map and when mouse hover on one country a line chart of carbon emission through years will be drawn below.

The geojson file and csv file are separated which means I have to call a function to search for data in the csv file while firing mouseover event which is not hard.

but the problem is when I try to draw the line chart. I can't use `y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.fookey; })])` since my data looks like this:

> {1990: "4768137.761", 1991: "4826703.418", 1992: "4922195.765", 1993: "5029767.21", 1994: "5121559.554", 1995: "5156168.7", 1996: "5286046.506", 1997: "5419440.965", 1998: "5456092.63", 1999: "5531691.502", 2000: "5713560.034", 2001: "5601404.839", 2002: "5650949.676", 2003: "5681664.468", 2004: "5790765.052", 2005: "5826393.624", 2006: "5737615.554", 2007: "5828696.5", 2008: "5656838.878", 2009: "5311840.184", 2010: "5433056.536", iso: "USA"}

is there a way I can set up the yAxis domain dynamically every time I have the mouseover event fired?

The code is here[github link here, everything is in the index.html](https://github.com/IanZhao/d3_map/)

For now, I've set up the yAxis by a hard rule with domain([0,10000]) is there anyway to walk around this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: uhmm is the code pasted here the actual file you are working with or the original csv has another structure? because like that it is not what a csv looks like

Comment: it's the data i'm working with. I found a solution though.

`d3.csv("path/to/file.csv")
    .row(function(d) { return {key: d.key, value: +d.value}; })
    .get(function(error, rows) { console.log(rows); });`

can be used to restructure the data which I think is the best solution for me.
Thanks Tom

Comment: ok, I think I was of no help here but seeing that structure associated with a csv made me think that maybe that was the reason why the code was not working properly. Glad you find a solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
d3.csv("path/to/file.csv")
.row(function(d) { return {key: d.key, value: +d.value}; })
.get(function(error, rows) { console.log(rows); });
```

this piece of code actually dose the trick. it allows me to reconstruct the data.

previously. my data was in csv file and looks like this

```
year country1 country2 country3 ...
1900 29292929 2324244  45446666
.
.
.
2010 3995959  9598858  43549599
```

so, with

> .row(function(d){ return {{key: d.key, value: +d.value}; })

I can choose which key and value I want to retrieve from csv file. for my own use, I did

> get(function(d){ return {year: d.year, value: +d[iso]})

here the value: +d[iso], the 'iso' is a string pass by other function. so this will finally give me an array of javascript objects like this

> [{'value': 2232323, 'year': '2010'} ......]

I think this makes thing much better, since for each country I hover on, it will give me an array of related data.